# Pandas and linear regression: multiple y values for single x

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a csv containing rental unit prices per night over a range of time. If the unit was rented, the price is listed under the day. If it was not rented, the price shows up as N/A. The data is structured like this:

```
bedrooms  day1   day2   day3...   day(n)
2          75    N/A     70       50
2          60    60      60       60
4          100   110     N/A      N/A
3          75    80      80       N/A
```

...and so on.

I'm reading this csv into pandas. I want to be able to use LinearRegression from scikit-learn to predict the price given the number of bedrooms. You do so like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
# X is numpy array or sparse matrix of shape [n_samples,n_features]
# y is numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_targets]
model.fit(X, y)
```

How can I use pandas to get my data in the correct format?

edit to clarify:

The correct format would have each price associated with a bedroom, like so:

```
bedrooms  price
2          75    
2          70       
2          50
2          60 
2          60 
2          60 
2          60 
4          100
4          110
3          80
3          80
```

Comment: each column in a `DataFrame` is a `Series` and `Series` object are 1) largely compatible with the `array` API (so they should work on their own) and 2) can be converted to an array with `numpy.array(df['column_name'])`

Comment: Ok. Then I have n arrays of pricing data (which still has to be cleaned).  Then what?

Comment: cleaned? what does that mean? provide examples of simple test cases that work.

Comment: I don't have any test cases per say, but if you include the value "N/A" when fitting data you get an error.

Comment: dataframes have a `dropna` method

Comment: You question clearly states: *How can I use pandas to get my data in the correct format?* so you need to show some examples of what that format is.

Comment: Updated my question for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an index to the `bedrooms` column and stack the dataframe.

Taking car to make sure everything has a name, the whole thing  looks like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas

datafile = StringIO("""\
bedrooms  day1   day2   day3     day(n)
2          75    N/A     70       50
2          60    60      60       60
4          100   110     N/A      N/A
3          75    80      80       N/A
""")

df = pandas.read_table(datafile, sep='\s+', index_col='bedrooms')
df.columns.names = ['days rented']
prices = df.stack()
prices.name = 'dollars'
prices.reset_index()
```

Which prints out:

```
    bedrooms days rented  dollars
0          2        day1       75
1          2        day3       70
2          2      day(n)       50
3          2        day1       60
4          2        day2       60
5          2        day3       60
6          2      day(n)       60
7          4        day1      100
8          4        day2      110
9          3        day1       75
10         3        day2       80
11         3        day3       80
```

Comment: Ah, df.stack() seems like the missing piece. Thanks a lot!